# Re-using a shape which requires two points in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot some persons on a grid. These persons are defined using `\def`, which exalts a point and a angle. But I like to pass two points instead of an angle: the position where the shape should be placed and the point to which the arrow shall point. The person shall be rotated accordingly, such that the the person looks in the direction of the arrow.

Here is a MWE. Note that I set the angle to some arbitrary number.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \def\person#1#2{
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1},rotate around={{#2}:(0.5cm,0.5cm)}]
      \draw (0.2cm,0.5cm) [thick, fill=green!50] circle (0.15cm);
      \draw (0.8cm,0.5cm) [thick, fill=green!50] circle (0.15cm);
      \draw (0.15cm,0.3cm) [thick, rounded corners=3.5, fill=green!50] rectangle (0.85cm,0.7cm);
      \draw (0.5cm,0.47cm) [thick, fill=black!50] circle (0.22cm);
    \end{scope}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);
    %Person 1
    \person{(1,1)}{32}; 
    \draw (1.5,1.5) [->, ultra thick] -- (2.5,3.5); %remove this line and put it to \person

    %Person 2
    \person{(3,2)}{124}; 
    \draw (3.5,2.5) [->, ultra thick] -- (5.5,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't use the exact syntax you asked for, but perhaps it is OK anyway. A person is defined using

```
\pic at (x,y) {person={xrel}{yrel}};
```

Here `(x,y)` is the coordinate where the (center of the) person is positioned, while `xrel` and `yrel` are the x- and y-components of the arrow. Hence,

```
\pic at (1,1) {person={2}{3}};
```

will place a person centered at (1,1), with an arrow ending at (1,1)+(2,3) = (3,4).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
pics/person/.style 2 args={
   code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\personangle}{atan2(#2,#1)}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\personwidth}{0.4cm}
      \draw [rotate=\personangle] (0,\personwidth) [thick, fill=green!50] circle[radius=0.15cm];
      \draw [rotate=\personangle] (0,-\personwidth) [thick, fill=green!50] circle[radius=0.15cm];
      \draw [rotate=\personangle] (-0.2cm,-\personwidth) [thick, rounded corners=3.5, fill=green!50] rectangle (0.2cm,\personwidth);
      \draw [rotate=\personangle] (0.05cm,0) [thick, fill=black!50] circle (0.22cm);
      \draw [->, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (#1,#2); 
}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);
    %Person 1
    \pic at (1,1) {person={1}{2}};

    %Person 2
    \pic at (3,2) {person={2}{1}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution adopts your syntax, but with some changes:

- The `xcolor` package is loaded by `tikz`, so it's not necessary to load it explicitly.
- The command is defined via `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. And it's placed in the preamble (not necessary, but I think it feels more organized).
- The structure of the command is as follows:

  ```
  \person{<position>}{<end arrow>}
  ```

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    bodypart/.style={draw, at start, sloped, rotate=-90}
}

\newcommand{\person}[2]{%
    \draw[->, thick] (#1)-- node[bodypart,rounded corners=1.2mm, 
                                    text width=4.5mm, fill=green!50] {} 
                            node[bodypart,rounded corners=.8mm, fill=green!50,
                                    text width=3mm]  {}
                            node[bodypart,circle, fill=black!50,rotate=-90] {} (#2);        
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);

    \person{1,1}{1,3}
    \person{3,2}{2,4} 
    \person{3,0}{4,2}   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `xcolor` is necessary, it's what allows you to say `black!50`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yeah, but... it's loaded by Tikz, so what was wrong with the previous wording?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I overreacted. My initial thought when reading "The `xcolor` package is not necessary in this code" was that it meant that "none of `xcolor`s features are used".

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem! By previous wording I meant last revision. `xcolor` would be necessary if `tikz` wasn't there, no? Anyway, the current revision is fine to me. :)